# How to align textbox to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have the a textbox used as a search field as follows that I want to align to the right:

```
<div class="col-md-6 search-form" style="padding:13px 0;">
    <form action="/search" method="post">
       <input type="search" name="q" style="max-width: 300px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here...">
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried surrounding it with another div to attempt to do so using text-align as shown below but it didn't align exactly where I want it

```
.new-search-div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of where I am trying to align it...
[image: align textbox right]

Comment: Is bootstrap `col-md-offset-2` as a class example perhaps something you're looking for?... http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/LUTE2CSVmg since you use bootstrap, there are already pre-defined classes for tasks like this... check 'all classes' button, and play a little with your markup.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-align:right;` will only right align text elements.

It appears that your are using bootstrap. You could try giving your form a class of `pull-right`, which is a bootstrap class for float right.

```
 <form action="/search" method="post" class="pull-right">
    <input type="search" name="q" style="max-width: 300px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here...">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `align:right;`, there's no such CSS rule, use `float:right;` instead.

(The element will be aligned to the right of the parent element, so you might need to apply that on the parent `form` instead, if you don't see it changing.)

Answer (score 0):

Already tried to give the Input a `float: right;` ?